# How to merge images and a music into a 30FPS video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have around 9000 images, which are named: `X0.png`, `X1.png`, ..., `X9000.png`

The music is 5minutes long. And I would like to generate a 30FPS video.

I know, there is a command-line tool, called `ffmpeg`. But the parameters are very complicated, and the name of the images makes the situation also problematic. Because alphabetical `X12.png` comes before `X2.png`, which is not the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a tool like [Advanced Renamer](http://www.advancedrenamer.com/) to rename the images with padding so that ffmpeg uses them in the correct order. If using AR, use method `New Name` with pattern `Y<Inc Nr:0001>`. Make sure the ordering of the input within AR is correct before you process the renaming.

Then, use ffmpeg like this

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i Y%04d.png -i musicfile -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest movie.mp4
```

(the `-shortest` ends the movie when the shorter of the two - images or music - ends.